# Windows 8.1 phone is not being registered

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, registration

I have a windows 8.1 phone, nokia Lumia 630, whenever I try to register my phone with windows phone developer registration (8.1), Its not being registered, but its being registered with version 8, but in my Visual Studio I am unable to find tool such as windows phone 8. though windows phone 8.1 is there.

Problem is if I register my phone with version 8, I cannot run my app or if I go for version 8.1 for registration its not detecting the device.

Comment: It is a bug had faced the same issue. Even though it says unable to register through windows 8.1 but it would have already registered you can deploy your app and test.

Comment: Do let me know if the issue was fixed or not

Comment: Yes Jerin, it has been fixed, I repaired the software by running installation again.

Comment: My laptop is not hyper-v supported, how  can I deploy app without hyper-v? any idea Jerin?

Comment: Well you need to enable virtualization through bios. Are you sure your laptop doesnt support hyper V?? I am sorry to say without hyper V I dont think you would be able to deploy the app.

Comment: yeah, now I am deploying only in Device, no emulator ..